# fox pro query to return sequential row number

Tags: c#, oledb, visual-foxpro

Is there any function like  ROW_NUMBER() of sql server to return the sequential number of a row in visual fox pro?Actually i am using oledb command in c# to retrieve data from fox pro. I need something like row_number() function to select few rows at a time(like paging concept)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx%20MSDN%20Library), the ROW_NUMBER function returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

Visual FoxPro has a RECNO function that returns the current record number in the current or specified table.  Review the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7tz3hhk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: But there is a small problem. while using joins i am not able to return values between for example 1 to 10

Comment: There is a better chance of getting help if you share the SQL.

Comment: Select field1,field2, from table1 inner join table2 on table1.field1=table2.field11 where recno() between 1 and 10.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: `recno()` will not necessarily give a sequential number on a table. Deleted records remain in the table with a deleted() tag and will not go away until the table is packed. Until the table is packed, the record number will stay in use, even though you can't see the record while browsing the table.

From your SQL statement I *think* you need to specify which table you want the `recno()` to come from.